# Memory leak, Pointer changing reference

Tags: pointers, reference, free, calloc, portaudio

I'm writing some signal processing routine, using the PortAudio library. I'm using a 
stucture which contains a pointer to float which is intended to be used as a buffer. I then pass it to an audio callback function.

My problem is that after callback processing is finished, my pointer has changed reference and thus cannot be freed. This is not such a big deal but the thing is that I don't understand when and how the pointer reference is changed and I'm getting a feel like I'm missing something important.

Here is a simplified version of the code :

```
typedef struct{

float* tmp;
//other stuff
} Data;

Data data;
data.tmp = NULL;
data.tmp = (float*) calloc(N,sizeof(float));// N is the size of the buffer

Pa_OpenDefaultStream(some args, //opens a PortAudio stream and passes tmp to callback
                            callback,
                            &data );
```

A stream is then started in another high priority thread and the callback is being executed as many times as needed. During callback tmp is being used as a ring buffer and is constantly being copied new data to.

```
static int callback(args,void* data){

Data* x = (Data*) tmp;
x->tmp = update();
}
```

where update() returns a pointer to a float which is initialized the same way as tmp is (calloc).

```
float* update(){
//do stuff
return m_tmp2;
}

float* m_tmp2 = (float*) calloc(N,sizeof(float));//same N as before
```

But after the stream is closed I get an error when calling free before quitting.

```
free(data.tmp);//throws a SIGABRT error
```

Some breakpoint debugging showed me that the reference of the pointer is being changed during the callback processing, but I don't get when and how it happens because everything else runs smoothly. It must be something during the callback execution, but I'm sure update() returns a pointer that is the same size as tmp. Or is it link with PortAudio ?

Please, any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I understand it right. You allocated the float (x.tmp) every time the callback function is called..

```
static int callback(args,void* data){

Data* x = (Data*) tmp;
x->tmp = update();
}
```

I assume the above is typo, you actually mean

```
static int callback(args,void* data){

Data* x = (Data*) data;
x->tmp = update();
}
```

Well, you're actually change the pointer value of tmp by assigning it update() because it's reallocate a new memory location in heap and changed the pointing location of the tmp..

```
float* update(){
//do stuff
return m_tmp2;
}
```

The data.tmp must have pointed to a new location every time the callback function is called.. So, I don't see why it doesn't behave as you described.. 
That's the correct behavior already.. Maybe I miss anything?

and maybe you should provide a mechanism to keep track of the buffer.. so all tmp (float *) you allocate for your circular buffer can be freed (not just the first one before the first callback is called..

Comment: Thank you Ari ! I got confused with all these pointer passing, and now that you've pointed out the problem it makes total sense. I've checked out in the debugger and actually the adress of *m_tmp2 matches data.tmp. Also thanks for the tip, but actually i'm assigning m_tmp2 adress only once. It's a member variable of the class which contains update() so it's always returning the same adress. But I guess it's just the wrong way to do it. Maybe I'll do something like  `update(data.tmp)`and copy the values inside the method (using some memcpy) instead of returning pointers.